# I can see another computer's shared iTunes library even though they are not sharing their library

Tags: itunes, mac, windows, music, sharing

For some reason, from my own iTunes library on my Mac, I can see another computer's (running Windows 7) iTunes shared library, even though they are not sharing their library (via Preferences -> Sharing).

I myself have shared my own iTunes library, and they can see it just fine. But I should not be able to see the other person's library when they are not sharing it. I checked the preferences myself.

Also, my own iTunes is logged into my iTunes account, while the other computer is not logged in to any iTunes account.

Why is the other computer's iTunes library visible to my own iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

are you guys on the same network. If so its possible that everyone on that network can access the everyone's shared library without any permissions as iTunes looks at them as home network. 
If you change network sharing type to public places ... Then this should not happen .

Comment: Do you have any documentation you could link to for more information on this?